# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ClientsProvider> above this Clients Widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting a list of clients from the Api, in a clients' list screen, when I want to Update a client, I navigate through DetailClient Screen than navigating through Edit client screen,
the update is working perfect ..but I wanted to navigate back through the first screen "clients list" from the alert dialogue to see the update in the clients' list.
the code is shown as bellow:

```
  Future<void> _saveForm() async {
    _form.currentState!.save();

     if (_client.id!.isNotEmpty) {
       await Provider.of<ClientsProvider>(context, listen: false).updateClients(_client.id!, _client);
         showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Client has been updated!'),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => Clients())));
                    },
                    child: Text('Okay'),
                  ),
                ],
              ));
     }else{
```

I had the following error while trying to navigate:

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Clients Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include... the provider

thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your top widget with `MultiProvider` to be able to locate your provider across the context.

```
void main(){
   runApp(
      MultiProvider(
       providers: [
         Provider<ClientsProvider>(
            create: (_) ClientsProvider(),
         )
       ],
       child: YourFirstWidget(),
      )
 );

}
```

Comment: it still the same problem bro!

Comment: Please update your question including the place where you declare your provider